# I am using htmx javascript API how do I get the response from server

Tags: django, ajax, htmx

My code block looks like this, basically when a modal is triggered I send a GET request and retrieve the response, it does send the request alright, but I am unable to see (or to put it better) to get the response from the server via .then() from htmx. I am using the example from there documentation.

```
htmx.ajax('GET',
    '/user-related-comment/',
    { swap: 'none', values: { userId: userId } }
).then(data => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

`data` is `undefined` when logged to browser console.

Comment: Try `.then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
})` with the extra brackets. Otherwise I would double check the backend to see what response comes.

Comment: Tried, Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that needs to do this, an option will be to listen to `'htmx:afterOnLoad'` event example.

```
    htmx.ajax('GET', '/example', '#myDiv').then(() => {
      document.body.addEventListener('htmx:afterOnLoad', event=>{
    console.log(event)
   // access response at event.detail.xhr.response
   // convert to JavaScript object by JSON.parse(event.detail.xhr.response)
  })
});
```

For some reason on first click, does nothing.

Comment: The point of htmx is to inject the html response directly into the DOM by providing swap and target argument to ajax method. If you want to manipulate the content then this solution is fine, although you should put it outside of ajax callback scope.

Comment: That's good, you can add example for other newbie like me to use as  reference. also adding `none` to the target and removing `swap` on the htmx.ajax() makes it work like jquery ajax functionality.

Comment: I found myself doing something similar when coding with django. it's not all the time that the hx-<attr> on the html/django-template is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of `htmx.ajax()` method is to trigger HTMX logic: do request, take response and insert it into the document. It's not meant to be used for just fetching the data from the server.

You clearly could use `htmx:afterOnLoad` to get the response, this could be considered as a valid option if you need to get response inserted somewhere on the page **and** do some additional manual processing. In that case you need to add event listener **before** sending the ajax request (that's why it doesn't work on the first click).

In case you just need to fetch the data, all you need is either `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Fetching_data.

### Fetching using HTMX

Based on you question, I assume you just need to get the response (based on `swap: 'none'` option), so here's how you can do that using HTMX (not sure why you would want to do so):

There's `handler` field in the `context` object that `htmx.ajax` could accept in third argument. Here's a function that will return XHR request back

```
function doHtmxAjax(method, url, options) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        options = options || {};
        htmx.ajax(method, url, {
            ...options,
            swap: 'none',
            handler: (_, r) => resolve(r.xhr)
        })
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
doHtmxAjax('GET',
    '/user-related-comment/',
    { values: { userId: userId } }
).then(data => {
    console.log(data)
})
```